# Loop finishing with error

Tags: excel, vba

I need to look for each row that has the phrase " Total" in it, insert rows above and below it, format other cells in and around that same row, remove the phrase " Total" from the cell, and repeat the process for all other rows in the report.

The macro I've developed, once it's found and replaced all of the instances of " Total", I get the Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

I would like to finish the loop without ending up with the error as this has to be executed on multiple sheets.  Here is the meat of the code:

```
'EmployerSummariesAddedForRegionsOnTabs Macro
Dim FoundCell As Range, LastCell As Range
Dim FirstAddr As String
With Range("D3:D3000")
    Range("D3").Select
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
Set FoundCell = Range("D1:D3000").Find(What:=" Total", After:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
End If
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    Set FoundCell = Range("D1:D3000").FindNext(After:=FoundCell)

    COLUMNS("D:D").Select
    Selection.Find(What:=" Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Total", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveCell.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .
    .
    .
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is giving you the error?

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to creating an object variable. First you must declare the object variable.
this error occurs because you didn't set a object correctly it is quite the same as null refrence exception if you have programming experience.
I ran your code and it seems that it doesn't do anything at all! **Not even an error!** so I assume that your error must because of somewhere else in your code.
any way this lines replace any total in active worksheet with nothing:

```
Cells.Replace What:=" Total", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```